# Check box to enable add-ons in blender is missing

Tags: add-on, customization

Hello everyone I am on version 2.77a of Blender.  I am trying to enable a few add-ons but I am having difficulty doing do as I can't seem to find the check box to click in order to enable them.  This is what I am looking at from the User Preferences window in the add-ons tab.  Dos anyone know how to get that check mark there?  Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The check box you're after is located on the left side.
[image]

Comment: Thank you, I was looking at some old tutorials where those were on the right side and not on the left side of the screen.

Comment: @undyinglight You're welcome. :)